# The font of one header will not change, but the font of others will, what can I do?

Tags: html, css, github, fonts, github-pages

I am creating a website and trying to change the font to Russo One. I have done it many times before but cannot for this one text element. I am using CSS positioning and more in the element and they work fine.

The HTML is:

```
<div class="seen">
<h1>As Seen On</h1>
</div>
```

The CSS is:

```
.seen {
    color: #000000;
    font-family: 'Russo One', -apple-system, BlinkMacSystemFont, 'Segoe UI', Roboto, 'Helvetica Neue', Arial, sans-serif, 'Apple Color Emoji', 'Segoe UI Emoji', 'Segoe UI Symbol', 'Noto Color Emoji';
    text-align: center;
    position: relative;
    top: 40px;
    right: 20px;
}
```

You can view the GitHub repository at: https://github.com/t0091/bootstrap

Comment: Can you post the rest of your code? Are you importing the font?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Bootstrap CSS for `h1` is taking precedence currently.

Using this as your CSS target will fix the issue:

```
.seen > h1
```

Comment: I did test this on your page and it worked. Not sure what the downvote is for

Comment: I did not downvote that, I am sorry but I cannot upvote either as my account is too new.

Comment: Great! Glad to help and welcome to Stack Overflow. (Side note, your other sections on that page are using <section> tags and other classes to format the header so you could look at those to try to match it as well. This is a quick easy fix though).